# Как исправить Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Начал смотреть что такое Hibernate и БД PostgreSQL, но столкнулся с проблемой. Idea выкидывает следующее сообщение

```
Jul 28, 2018 3:03:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
Jul 28, 2018 3:03:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 1 and column 87 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    at DAO.DataDAO.add(DataDAO.java:10)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 1 and column 87 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 87; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:468)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:126)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 87; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1901)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement(StAXEventConnector.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:445)
    ... 10 more
```

Идея у меня такая: хочу сформировать таблицу, вот мапинг

```
<hibirnate-mapping>
    <class name="logic.Data" table="dates">
        <id column="ssoid" name="id" type="java.lang.String"></id>

        <property column="ts" name="time" type="java.lang.Long"></property>
        <property column="grp" name="groupEvent" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="type" name="event" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="subtype" name="subevent" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="url" name="url" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="orgid" name="organization" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="formid" name="formId" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="code" name="code" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="ltpa" name="itpa" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="sudirresponse" name="sudirresponse" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property column="ymdh" name="date" type="java.util.Date"></property>
    </class>
</hibirnate-mapping>
```

Класс для Data - это обычный POJO, есть get и set для всех полей и конструктор без параметров.

Вот конфиг для Hibirnate:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test"</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"</property>-->

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="logic/Data.hbm.xml"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Возможно проблема в том что IDEA мне выделяет красным путь к ресурсу

```
<mapping resource="logic/Data.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

За добавление в БД и таблицу отвечает класс DataDAO

```
import logic.Data;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import util.HibernateUtil;

    public class DataDAO {
    
        public void add(Data data){
            try(Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(data);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

И вот структура моего проекта:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Отсутствует определение документа

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Здесь циферами указана версия Hibernate, но вы можете подправить к нужной версии.

В следующем [примере](http://internetka.in.ua/hibernate-setup/) можно найти файл конфигурации

> Настройку Hibernate можно выполнить 4 способами: с помощью
> конфигурационного файла hibernate.cfg.xml, динамически в коде, с
> помощью установки System Properties и при помощи файла
> hibernate.properties. Рассмотрим первые два варианта как наиболее
> часто используемые. hibernate.cfg.xml
>
> Пример конфигурационного файла:
>
> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
>         "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
>         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
>  
> <hibernate-configuration>
>  
>     <session-factory>
>  
>         <!-- Настройки подключения к БД -->
>         <property name="connection.driver_class">
>                        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>         </property>
>  
>         <property name="connection.url">
>                        jdbc:mysql://localhost
>         </property>
>  
>         <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
>         <property name="connection.password">password</property>
>  
>         <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
>  
>         <!-- SQL диалект -->
>         <property name="dialect">
>                        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>         </property>
>  
>         <!-- Включить автоматическое управление контекстом сессии -->
>         <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
>  
>         <!-- Отключение кеша второго уровня  -->
>         <property name="cache.provider_class">
>                        org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
>         </property>
>  
>         <!-- Вывод в консоль SQL-запросов -->
>         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
>  
>         <!-- Подключение объектов сущностей -->
>         <mapping package="hibernate.db"/>
>         <mapping class="hibernate.db.User"/>
>  
>     </session-factory>
>  
> </hibernate-configuration>
> ```
>
> По умолчанию Hibernate ищет этот файл в корневой папке src директорий
> ("/hibernate.cfg.xml"). Но при необходимости ему можно задать любое
> месторасположение, об этом речь пойдет немного позже.